# How do I transform the dates to weekdays with the subset function?

Tags: r, date, subset

I am asked to subset the dates and nicknames of R-updates. I am further asked to exclude terms with the word NA and to transform the dates into weekdays. Whilst I have managed to exclude the NAs, I do not know how to transform the dates into weekdays while simultaneously subsetting.

```
subset(Rversions, select = nickname:date, !is.na(Rversions$nickname))
 wday(dates, label = TRUE)
```

The output:

```
                nickname       date
79             Great Pumpkin 2011-10-31
80       December Snowflakes 2011-12-22
81       Gift-Getting Season 2012-02-29
82             Easter Beagle 2012-03-30
83      Roasted Marshmallows 2012-06-22
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `subset` function will allow you add/transform the data. You can use the `transform` function.

```
result <- transform(subset(Rversions, select = cnickname:date, !is.na(nickname)),
                    date = weekdays(date))

result
```